# How to use CssStyleCollection for a UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, custom-controls

I am wanting to do custom rendering of the CSS styling, as such I created a new UserControl.

From there, I thought it'd be easy just create a new CssStyleCollection under the name Style. It does not work though! How do I make this code compile? (just an example)

```
class MyControl : UserControl{
  CssStyleCollection Style=new CssStyleCollection(); //compiler error on the `new..` 
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. CssStyleCollection is a sealed class, but it is not static. How do I instantiate a new one!?

Also, the compiler error given is

> The type
>   System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection has
>   no constructors defined

Comment: Why are you trying to use this exact class?

Comment: A UserControl typically consists of a collection of other controls. Let's say it contains a TextBox and a Button. Is it really intuitive to have CSS properties on the UserControl itself? What would setting the font-size do, for example? Affect the TextBox, the Button or both?

Comment: Actually it's more of a `HeaderStyle` and `ContentStyle` type thing with the header and content both being treated as if they were in panels, except for it is easy to inherit from and all controls go into the Content panel(as far as rendering is concerned, that is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CssStyleCollection is created from a Style object; a Style object has a  GetStyleAttributes method that returns a CssStyleCollection, so create a Style object, assign all the props you want, and return CssStyleCollection.  Also, it requries IUrlResolutionService, which is a reference to the page or a control.

Comment: Reference to MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.getstyleattributes%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style style = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style();
CssStyleCollection cssStyles = style.GetStyleAttributes(someControl);

Answer (score 1):

Ok, technically the only proper way is to hack .Net and use reflection to call it's private constructor... see http://bart-at-work.blogspot.com/2008/11/create-cssstylecollection-instance.html

Well, I figure that a CssStyleCollection doesn't have anything too special in it, so what I did was a simple yet elegant hack without reflection.

```
CssStyleCollection Style=new Panel().Style;
```

I'm not sure how "safe" it is, but it works on .Net and Mono, so it's good enough for me.

Comment: It's never proper to use private reflection to instantiate a type.

Comment: It didn't feel right to me either, thats why I did the `new Panel().Style` thing.. The reflection thing is the only way I found to do it when googling though